# Why is my JAVA_HOME variable that I setup not working?

Tags: android, environment-variables, java-home, system-variable

I'm trying to install and use Android Studio. However, when I run the program after installing, it gives me this error:

[image: Can't Launch Android Studio]

I went into my control panel and added an Environment Variable under System variables that looks like this:

[image: This is my variable I set up]

I restarted my computer after making this, but it still doesn't work. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have a 32-bit installation of the JDK and Android Studio is asking for a 64-bit installation.  You can tell it is 32-bit because the path you used for JAVA_HOME is located in 'Program Files (x86)' (where the '(x86)' indicates 32-bit programs).  You need to install a 64-bit version of the JDK.

Comment: Ahh, okay thanks, I knew I had the 64bit installed but I was in the wrong folder. Thanks a lot!